# Bootstrap CSS does not apply to new dynamically added HTML using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap in order to style my webpage and it works almost perfect,
but when i'm trying to add new html to the page using $.append(). then the new html does not get the default bootstrap style.
this is my relevant html:

```
 <div id="lines">
        <div id="line1">
            <input type="tel" class="Numbers" id="Number1" />
            <input type="tel" class="Numbers" id="Number2" />
            <input type="tel" class="Numbers" id="Number3" />
            <input type="tel" class="Numbers" id="Number4" />
            <input type="tel" class="Numbers" id="Number5" />
            <input type="tel" class="Numbers" id="Number6" />
            <input type="tel" class="Numbers" id="StrongNumber1" style="background-color:cyan"/>
            <button class="btn btn-primary addbtns" id="btnAdd1" onclick="addLine()">+</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary addbtns" id="btnMinus1" disabled="disabled">-</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is my JQuery:

```
function addLine() {
$('#btnAdd' + lineCounter).attr('disabled', 'true');
$('#btnMinus' + lineCounter).attr('disabled', 'true');

++lineCounter;

var line = "<div id='line" + lineCounter + "'>" +
                "<input type='tel' class='Numbers' id='Number" + lineCounter + "' />" +
                "<input type='tel' class='Numbers' id='Number" + lineCounter + "' />" +
                "<input type='tel' class='Numbers' id='Number" + lineCounter + "' />" +
                "<input type='tel' class='Numbers' id='Number" + lineCounter + "' />" +
                "<input type='tel' class='Numbers' id='Number" + lineCounter + "' />" +
                "<input type='tel' class='Numbers' id='Number" + lineCounter + "' />" +
                "<input type='tel' class='Numbers StrongNumber' id='StrongNumber" + lineCounter + "' style='background-color:cyan' />" +
                "<button class='btn btn-primary addbtns' id='btnAdd" + lineCounter + "' onclick='addLine()'>+</button>" +
                "<button class='btn btn-primary addbtns' id='btnMinus" + lineCounter + "' onclick='removeLine()'>-</button>" +
            "</div>";
$('#lines').append(line).fadeIn('slow');
}
```

---

edit:
Ok i tried to reproduce the bug with the simplest page possible and a simple append. also switched the JS ' to " like @Sherbrow suggested, and it still not working..

here is my HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
<head></head>
<body dir="rtl">
<div id="lines">
        <div id="line1">
            <input type="tel" class="Numbers" id="Number1" />
            <input type="tel" class="Numbers" id="Number2" />
            <input type="tel" class="Numbers" id="Number3" />
            <input type="tel" class="Numbers" id="Number4" />
            <input type="tel" class="Numbers" id="Number5" />
            <input type="tel" class="Numbers" id="Number6" />
            <input type="tel" class="Numbers" id="StrongNumber1" style="background-color:cyan"/>
            <button class="btn btn-primary addbtns" id="btnAdd1" onclick="addLine()">+</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary addbtns" id="btnMinus1" disabled="disabled">-</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

my CSS:

```
body
{
    background-color:#E46C0B;
    text-align:center;
}
.Numbers
{
    width: 16px;
}
```

my JavaScript:

```
var lineCounter=1;
function addLine() {
$('#btnAdd' + lineCounter).attr('disabled', 'true');
$('#btnMinus' + lineCounter).attr('disabled', 'true');

++lineCounter;

var line = '<div id="line' + lineCounter + '">' +
                '<input type="tel" class="Numbers" id="Number' + lineCounter + '1" />'   +
                '<input type="tel" class="Numbers" id="Number' + lineCounter + '2" />' +
                '<input type="tel" class="Numbers" id="Number' + lineCounter + '3" />' +
                '<input type="tel" class="Numbers" id="Number' + lineCounter + '4" />' +
                '<input type="tel" class="Numbers" id="Number' + lineCounter + '5" />' +
                '<input type="tel" class="Numbers" id="Number' + lineCounter + '6" />' +
                '<input type="tel" class="Numbers StrongNumber" id="StrongNumber"' +  lineCounter + '" style="background-color:cyan" />' +
                '<button class="btn btn-primary addbtns" id="btnAdd"' + lineCounter + '" onclick="addLine()">+</button>' +
                '<button class="btn btn-primary addbtns" id="btnMinus"' + lineCounter + '" onclick="removeLine()">-</button>' +
            '</div>';
$('#lines').append(line);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the answers :)

Comment: Your HTML page should have unique id's ?? That might not be a issue in this case.. But make sure you have unique

Comment: [Working here](http://jsbin.com/uconof/1/edit).

Comment: @SheikhHeera.. Check this.. type="tel"  id='Number" + lineCounter.. 6 each input with same id

Comment: @Sushanth--, Yes I got it, that's why I've upvoted your comment.

Comment: Oops, thank u. But this isn't solving the problem :(

Comment: @DanelWolloch, didn't you see [this is working here](http://jsbin.com/uconof/1/edit).

Comment: Maybe your relevant HTML is not enough. Try to reproduce the bug with the simplest page possible and a simple append. If you can't, work your way up from the working simple page to what you have know, step by step. (you should use `"` instead of `'` for your attributes)

Comment: Maybe try to wrap your script around this `$(function() { your code });` and put the JS-files in the footer of your page, after the closing `</body>`

Comment: Did you ever solve this Danel?

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be the case that the CSS would not apply to newly created DOM elements. This can, however, happen for JavaScript.

There's a few things that should change in your code, whether it actually fixes the issue or not:

- IDs are meant to be used only once. Classes can be reused. Please change your `line` and `lines` IDs to classes so you can create multiple elements and style them all under one umbrella.
- Don't sweat the " or '. JavaScript will work fine with both as long as "s close "s and 's close 's.
- I noticed you're styling the width of input boxes. Insure there is not already a `min-width` specified.

If these suggestions don't work, please create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) so we can reproduce the problem.